# Memory leak on fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, fragment, android-support-library

[image]I have two fragments one list and one detail fragment. On list item click I a hiding list fragment and adding detail fragment on back press detail fragment is popped automatically I am just calling super.onBackPressed() but issue is it is creating so many references of detail fragments resulting is memory leaks

Following is my code

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.hide(this);
    ft.add(containerId, detailFragment, "detail");
    ft.addToBackStack("detail");
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
```

I don't want to view to be recreated view when user press back button on detail fragment thats why I used above approach. Also with current implementation when I press back button recylerview scroll possition and other data I don't have to save

My Activity has only following code it inflates list fragment

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.FragmentContainer1, ListFragment.newInstance(), TAG).commit();

    }
```

Comment: Please post the complete activity code.

Comment: `it is creating so many references of detail fragments resulting is memory leaks` How sure you are about that? Where from have you seen those leakages?

Comment: added activity code and memory allocation. Look at count for DealFragment

Comment: You're only adding fragments… add add add add… try `replace` ;)

Comment: what should be the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing wrong is that you are adding fragments each time to the container again and again by calling `add` method:

In your case you should use `replace` method and add your list fragment to the backstack. Here's how you should start your detail fragment:

```
  FragmentManager fm  = getFragmentManager();

  fm.beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
  .addToBackstack(null)
  .commit();
```

To get back to your list fragment, which is in the back stack, just call:

```
fm.popBackStack();
```

EDIT:

Try this to show your list fragment:

```
protected void displayListFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (listFragment.isAdded()) { 
        ft.show(listFragment);
    } else { 
        ft.add(R.id.flContainer, listFragment, "ListFragment");
    }

    if (detailFragment.isAdded()) { 
        ft.remove(detailFragment);
    }

    ft.commit();
}
```

And this to show your detail fragment:

```
 protected void displayDetailFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (listFragment.isAdded()) { 
            ft.hide(listFragment);
        } 

        if (!detailFragment.isAdded()) { 
            ft.add(R.id.flContainer, detailFragment, "DetailFragment");
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: doing this does not restore recycler view scroll position and other things

Comment: You said that you don't need to save scroll position "Also with current implementation when I press back button recylerview scroll possition and other data I don't have to save"

Comment: I said with cureent implementation if i add replace scroll state is lost